# How to slide Update Panel content after updating

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an Update Panel that contains an image and a button. Image control displays one image at a time when clicked on "Next Image" Button and previous image on clicking "Previous Image" button. Code sample is something like this

```
protected void btnNext_Click(..)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl=getNextImageFromDatabase();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
protected void btnPrevious_Click(..)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl=getPreviousImageFromDatabase();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Now what I want to know is that is there any way I can slide image or whatever content in update panel to left when clicked on "Next Image" and similarly to right when clicked on "Previous Image"? Is there any way using AjaxToolKit or JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use the jquery fadeIn fadeOut methods which will look like a slide effect

See example here http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can simply animate margin-left to negative values, so Image would disapear. I personaly use this solution:

- User clicks on next/prev button
- Show loading image (a gif)
- Create image (`var img = new Image()`) in javascript
- set onload action for that image to move old one to left/right and append new image etc.
- get next/prev image url
- assign src of the created image, so when it's loaded the onload action is executed.

AjaxToolkit might not be the cleanest solution in this case. You will probably need to make some simple service that returns nex/prev image url, but that's only few lines of code...

Comment: Is AjaxToolkit ever the cleanest solution?

Comment: Good point. Looking back on my experiences with this extensions and hours wasted... ;-)